# Creating Dom Structure or Only Manipulating (Best Practice) (Hows does Google do it)

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

What is the best Practice in creating a RIA via JavaScript and the Google Closure Library?
To Have one HTML Site that gets loaded and the Javascript will creating all Dom elements or is it better to have multiple html sites where only some elements gets manipulated?

I mean our Application don't needed to be indexed and will only be hosted in internal networks, but I really don't know yet, whats better.
I think Google Mail is something that creates every Dom element on start and then won't switch the site, just loads json objects from the backend. I think this seems to be a good way to do it, but is this really the best way to do it?

How would you build your applications?

Comment: Linking and bookmarking will be a bit of a pain when your html is 100% created by javascript. I don't know if there are libraries that will inspect the location but it seems troublesome. I haven't got that much experience but found that (with Symfony for example) using `isXmlHttpRequest()` enables me to return only part of the normally returned response. Returning a list of articles for example instead of the main page (that includes the list of articles as an include). This way I don't need to over complicate request handling but still have parts of my page load through JS.

Comment: did you done something with closure templates?

Comment: No, didn't use the soy templates. Used twig and appended the new list of articles (served as html) to the list. Twig is (one of)the server side templating engine for Symfony.

Comment: yeah but we don't wanna run Symfony, we will be useing django or google go

Answer (score 1):

our applications need to be indexed to an extent. we use soy templates, render the initial html on the server, then use the decoration phase to enable the javascript controls. 
after the application has init'd (ala decorated) we just pull json and draw on the client.

In this way we get content to screen extremely fast and for the rest have a single page app. 
we also use html 5 history, thus when navigating to a different part of the app, the url changes, thus you can bookmark any page and we obviously have the ability to pre-render any page.

Comment: how do you change the url of a specific part of the app?
and yeah thanks for ur answer, i think we want to make the same thing.

do you only use post/get or do you use the whole ReSTful?

Comment: we use only POST and GET and then we also push a lot of data over long polling or sockets.

Comment: Sorry, posted too early. check this: goog.history.Html5History - we have a full routing system like spring/rails etc where we resolve /controller/action/args/args

Comment: Just one last question, whats your backend language? Ah and ty. Cant +1 your question yet due too my reputation

Comment: our backend is a combination of scala and java. I know there is a Go implementation of soy, but that is way behind. Some of the new features in soy are things like delegate templates, we cannot work without them.